# Generalization of Debreu's additive utility function $\sum_nu_n(x_n)$ with infinite number of commodities

Tags: microeconomics, mathematical-economics, preferences, theory, decision-theory

I want to generalize:  $\sum_nu_n(x_n)$.

Here $x_1,x_2,..,x_n,...$ are commodities. There are infinite number of commodities: $n\in\mathbb N$ or $n\in \mathbb R_+$

The following **not** a candidate: $\int_{n\in\mathbb R}u_n(x_n)d\mu$. It is not a candidate because we need **additional** assumptions for $\mu$ being a measure over sigma-field. By adding additional assumption that is too strong, we cannot say it is a good generalization.

What is too strong: assuming sigma-algebra or countably additive measure. Sigma algebra makes no sense when $n$ finite.

What assumption is acceptable: assuming non-sigma field, or any other assumption commonly assumed within finite settings.

One thing have in my mind is: $x\succsim y \iff \sum_{n\in\mathbb N}(u_n(x_n)-u_n(y_n))\geq0$. In this case we have $x\succ y$ when $x_n=2n$ and $y_n=n$

Relation to literature:

1. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11238-013-9391-2 This paper focuses on the infinite dimensional representation $\sum_n(u(x_n)-u(y_n))\geq 0$ which is similar to the representation above.
2. https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0022249674900315
   This paper is only distantly related because my question requires that all directions are separable.
3. https://www.jstor.org/stable/1909948 Fishburn's ECMA
4. link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-48773-6_3
   Debreu 1997

Comment: Could you explain what additional assumptions you consider 'too strong'? So it would be easier to understand your question. Because, when you pass  from finite to infinity necessarily there must be new assumptions, the passage from finite to infinity isn't 'painless'. Your question is interesting but needs details.

Comment: @BakerStreet Sure please bear with me for a moment

Comment: Of course, when you have time.

Comment: @BakerStreet Does this look better?

Comment: Yes, I think so. But, how can you define an integral and a measure without a sigma-algebra?

Comment: @BakerStreet I added two papers. The first one might be very helpful. I just find it a few minutes ago.

Comment: Moreover, I’m not sure that a sigma-algebra makes no sense for finite sets. Actually, finite is a particular case of countably infinite, where you add to the *n* finite sets an infinite number of empty sets. For example, the finite union of *n* sets $A_i$ can be written as $\cup _{i=0}^{n} A_i$= $(\cup _{i=0}^{n}A_i )\cup \emptyset \cup \emptyset \cup \emptyset ….$

Comment: Therefore, sigma (countable)- additivity implies finite additivity.

Comment: You talk about additional assumptions but not about the assumptions you are willing to make to start with. I'm not sure I understand what the question asks for.

Comment: @BakerStreet Sigma algebra is usually neither observable nor testable, though.

Comment: Of course, as many mathematical objects. It is just a definition, in set theory. I was just saying that a sigma-algebra is not necessarily something that pertains to countable infinite collections of sets, but also to finite collections: *a collection of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ is called a sigma-algebra provided it contains $\mathbb{R}$ and is closed with respect to the formation of complements and countable unions*. But, as I said above, a finite collection can be considered a countable collection if  infinite empty sets are added to the union.

Comment: So,  your objection that a sigma-algebra makes no sense for finite collections isn’t true, and it can be considered a generalization, in the sense that it encompasses also the finite case.

Comment: Maybe you can begin with this article, of 1997, by Debreu about additive preferences, that refers also to the infinite commodities case. 


https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-48773-6_3

Comment: @BakerStreet Let me try!